# Reverse a linked list in Swift

Tags: swift, data-structures

Reversing a linked list in Swift is easy. I have a working solution. However, while preparing for whiteboard interviews the version I produce quickly simply does not work and I cannot identify why.

I need to know why the following does not work - from the Playground I believe it is because

```
tail = previous
```

line errors and execution never completes.

```
func reverseLL (node: Node?) -> Node? {
    guard node != nil else { return nil }
    var tail : Node? = node
    var previous = node?.next
    while previous != nil {
        let tailRef = previous?.next
        previous?.next = tail
        tail = previous
        previous = tailRef
    }
    return tail
    }
```

My definition of the linked list is:

```
class Node: CustomStringConvertible {
    var data: Int
    var next: Node?

    var description: String {
        return String(data) + (next != nil ? next!.description : "")
    }

    init (data: Int) {
        self.data = data
        next = nil
    }

    func appendToTail(data: Int) {
        if (next != nil) {
            next?.appendToTail(data: data)
        }
        else {
            next = Node(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

My working version of reverseLL (which I accept is more 'Swifty') is as follows, but I believe it should be functionally identical to my earlier definition.

```
 func reverseLL (node: Node?) -> Node? {
guard node != nil else { return nil }
        var tail: Node?
        var headNode = node
        while let head = headNode {
            let tailRef = head.next
            head.next = tail
            tail = head
            headNode = tailRef
        }
        return tail
    }
```

So creating a linked list with

```
let ll = Node(data: 3)
ll.appendToTail(data: 4)
ll.appendToTail(data: 4)
ll.appendToTail(data: 5)
```

gives the data in order of 3445

and reversed through

```
reverseLL(node: ll)
```

gives the data in order of 5443

To be clear, why does the

```
tail = previous
```

line halt execution in my first definition of reverseLL?

Comment: Where is the definition of the LinkedList class (if any)?

Comment: @Carpsen90 Ok, we can step through the execution of that version, and during the first iteration it is nil. That is absolutely fine - when we reverse a linked list the last element will link (though .next) to a nil element (as it is the end of the LL). Execution works as expected here (a ll of data 3->4->4->5 reversed is 5->4->4->3), but good check.

Comment: The class Node represents a LinkedList. Any given node within a linked list is also a linked list, so here it is named as Node.

Comment: Ok, it completed all the HackerRank tests but it's entirely possible it doesn't work and there is a slip somewhere. On my machine, however it appears to function as to reverse the order of a linked list. So for clarity I added in how I create a simple linked list, and the results it gives.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the first definition doesn't reverse !

Comment: Ok here is a JDoodle version which reverses 3->4->4->5 and prints the reversed ll to the console. https://www.jdoodle.com/a/T7g

Comment: I have a working definition that you said did not work and I should start with fixing that (you deleted the comment). So I've confirmed that it does work, and used JDoodle to demonstrate that it works, and the node definition is correct. I do not know why the non-working version does not work. That is my initial question!

Comment: Algorithmically both versions should be the same, so if one works (with the evidence shown here the more Swifty version does) the other should. The issue is with how the code works in Swift I believe, and that is my question. Why does the first version not complete?

Comment: You could remove the unnecessary comments and add any clarification to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version is more Swifty since you're using optional binding and avoiding the horrendous forced-unwrapping.

The problem in the first version is that `tail` is initially equal to `node`. In the example that you've given that is (**3->4->4->5**).

So when you do `previous?.next = tail` in the first iteration, `previous` becomes (**4->4->5->3->4->5->3->4->5->...**). Notice that The node with data equal to `5` now points to a node with data equal to `3`. Which creates an infinite loop.

---

**Simplification**

The guard statement could also be written as :

```
guard node?.next != nil else {
    return node
}
```

which would include lists with a single node.

Comment: Ok, in effect the slip was simply that the previous node should initially be set as the node. var previous = node

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the complete code including class, function and input and output things**

// First we are creating class to store the data of Linked List

```
class Node {
    var data: Int
    var next: Node?

    var description: String {
        return String(data) + (next != nil ? next!.description : "")
    }

    init (data: Int) {
        self.data = data
        next = nil
    }

    func appendToLast(data: Int) {
        if (next != nil) {
            next?.appendToLast(data: data)
        } else {
            next = Node(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

//Function that return the reversed Linked List

```
func reverseLinkedList(node: Node?) -> Node? {
guard node != nil else { return nil }
        var tail: Node?
        var headNode = node
        while let head = headNode {
            let tailRef = head.next
            head.next = tail
            tail = head
            headNode = tailRef
        }
        return tail
    }
```

//Input all the data which we have in the linkedlist and output of that inside the print function.

```
let ll = Node(data: 3)
ll.appendToLast(data: 4)
ll.appendToLast(data: 4)
ll.appendToLast(data: 5)
let reversedLL = reverseLinkedList(node: ll)
print(reversedLL?.description ?? "No Data")
```